# Registered Window Message TaskbarButtonCreated not received

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, wndproc

I am wanting to start looking at the Windows 7 TaskBar API. I have created a basic MFC Dialog Project but after registering the TaskbarButtonCreated message, it never gets sent to my WindowProc. Here is what I have:

```
LRESULT CTaskBarAPITestDlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(message == g_wmTBC)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Hit the message"));
        //This is never hit
    }
    return CDialogEx::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}

int CTaskBarAPITestDlg::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDialogEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    g_wmTBC = RegisterWindowMessage(_T("TaskbarButtonCreated"));
    //This works fine

    return 0;
}
```

The `AfxMessageBox` never gets hit. I have also tried adding a `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE` to my `MESSAGE_MAP` but that method doesn't get called either. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see where you are posting the "TaskbarButtonCreated" message.  You've registered it, but, never posted it so that it can be handled.

Comment: @rrirower as far as I understand windows is meant to post this message when it creates the task bar icon for the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I needed the following:

```
ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd(), g_wmTBC, MSGFLT_ALLOW, NULL);
ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_COMMAND, MSGFLT_ALLOW, NULL);
```

in my `OnInitDialog`.

**EDIT:**

This is because I was running the application with elevated privileges and so by default messages will not be received from a lower-privileged process unless you use `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx`. More info: [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202(v=vs.85).aspx).

Microsoft also have some example code doing the same thing [here on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/TaskbarThumbnailToolbar/ThumbnailToolbar.cpp)

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference for why this is required, ideally official documentation?